# Only getting one single client in my serverSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a server socket and i want to open it to multiple clients.
but only getting 1, and if i close that client, im not allowed to get any more client.

Server code:

```
public class Server {

  public void startServer() {
        final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);               
        Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InetAddress ip;
                    connect cn = new connect();
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9239);
                    Socket clientSocket;
                    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

                        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                        String HostName = "";
                        String HostIp = "";
                        String PC = "";

                        clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                        HostName = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName();
                        HostIp = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                        System.out.println(HostName + "/" + HostIp);

                        PC = HostName + "/" + HostIp;

                        cn.insert(PC);



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();
    }

   private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Got a client !");

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

When im using client, im getting the ip and the hostname, but, if i launch another client it wont listen to it.

What im doing wrong? I think is not necessary to upload my client code cause im getting the first, so i think im doing something wrong at this.

Comment: You should wrap the `serverSocket.accept()` call in a while loop so it can accept multiple clients.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the Thread into a while-loop, without it after creating one connection the code is finished and will stop.